# React native Firebase push notification Android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like use [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) into my react-native project and I have a problem when I would like send push notification to my current device (for testing) with token in params.

I have tested the example app from react-native-fcm, and Local notification work fine, i tried to send with a token but I don't no why, I receive nothing on my device.

Here's my code

```
render() {
         FCM.getFCMToken().then(token => { // token android
            firebaseClient.sendNotificationWithData(token)
        });
        //this.showLocalNotification()
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <AppNavigator />
            </Provider>
        );
}
```

I have already imported FirebaseClient and PushController

On console I have a success response but I don't receive notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check the permissions ? `FCM.requestPermissions();`
plus i had an issue with that and i had to add `"content_available": true,` to the payload.